# Sum up array values

Tags: php, arrays, sum

This is the array: http://www.stylechica.de/array.rtf (I can't copy it here)

I need to sum up ["PriceInformation"]["PriceInformation"]["PriceDetails"]["Price"] and allready tryed all kind of stuff like

```
foreach ($output["PriceInformation"]["PriceDetails"]["Price"] as $product)

echo array_sum($product);
```

but it just won't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Would help if you said what language you are working in, to start with.

Comment: You can also almost certainly find the answer you're looking for by searching for "sum up array values" with the language you're using into Google.

Comment: I allready did but thats yn multidimensional array

Comment: even var_dump shows only one value. I cant'explain the problem very clear just look at the file

Comment: Not opening that file, you have to post the relevant parts here. Don't just link to it, let alone a file we have to download.

Comment: You have posted a question pointing to an rtf (rich text file) without clarifying the language you want to use.

Comment: Ok look here: http://www.stylechica.de/look/

Comment: Language? PHP as the example code above is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `$product` refers to each iteration of `$output["PriceInformation"]["PriceDetails"]["Price"]`, you can't sum the entire array like this. The best way to do it would be to add it to a variable as you go:

```
$your_sum = 0;
foreach($output as $value) {
    $your_sum += $value['PriceInformation']['PriceDetails']['Price'];
}
echo 'Sum: ' . $your_sum;
```